# SetTimeOut or SetInterval trigger event fast

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Here is my code

> setInterval(function()
>   {
>                   $("#<%=cmbResCityStatEdit.ClientID%>
>   option[text='"+ $(
>   '#<%=lblCity.ClientID%>' ).text()
>   +"']").attr("selected",true); $("#<%=cmbResCityStatEdit.ClientID%>
>   option:selected").text())
>                },1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

time is in microsecond, so you are defining an interval of 1/1000th of second...
and network overloading has no impact in this, since you are simply executing the code in your client after a delay.

P.s.: next time, please, ask a more clear question, I'm not even sure if my answer has been useful.

Comment: I just want to know settimeout or setinterval is more faster

Comment: @fcalderan Can you please tel me

Comment: The functions are doing (almost) exactly the same. The only difference is, that `setTimeout` will only trigger your function once and `setInterval` will trigger it continuously given the interval time you specified.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout and setInterval are exactly the same speed, they are different statements though.  setTimeout will run your function after the timeout, setInterval will run it continuously after a set amount of time between each run.